# How can I resolve the comparison between pointer and integer of "k" and "my_argv" in the following code?

Tags: c, pointers

- my argv contains the list of total 10 values.
- I need to do some function operation under the for loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    int my_argc;
    char **my_argv;
    if (argc > 2) 
    {
        if (!strcmp(argv[2], "all")) 
        {
            my_argc = 3;
            my_argv = (char *[]){ "0x1", "0x2", "0x3" };
        } else 
        {
           my_argc = argc - 2;
           my_argv = argv + 2;
        }
        int i;
        for (i=0; i<my_argv; i++) 
         {
            handle_arg(my_argv[i]);
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- However I get this error as below? Like I tried changing from int k to char k and also using atoi? So how can I compare k with my_argv?

```
warning: comparison between pointer and integer
    for (k=0; k<my_argv; k++)
```

Comment: `my_argc = 12;`..change to `int my_argc = 12;` at least.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , I have edited it. And posted the original code. Where-in I have declared all the variables, just that I am unable to figure out why the warning is being reported when comparing k with argv in for loop?

Comment: from the error `k<my_argv;` this is what you need to fix , what are you really trying there, checking number of args or different?

Comment: Better to show full code and explain what are you trying with input and output.

Comment: You've put an `else` before an `if`... how did you not get an error for this?

Comment: @IrAM , I got that I needed to replace k<my_argc, as I need to compare only 3 arguments passed to the program.

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1, I have now displayed the full code.

Comment: Note that `strcmp()` returns zero when both passed strings matches.

Comment: @SouravGhosh , also I was wondering if I could ask another question like ? -> "all" for this my_argv = (char *[]){ "0x1", "0x2", "0x3" }; is not being called properly? Or did I miss not defining "all" properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by the naming of variables,

- `my_argv` contains the actual arguments passed to the program invocation.
- `my_argc` contains the count of the arguments passed to the program invocation.

I highly doubt you need to compare the counter to `my_argv`, rather you should be comparing it against the number of command line argument, which is held in `my_argc`.

---

After the edit:

Yes, your code

```
 for (i=0; i<my_argv; i++)
```

should be

```
for (i=0; i<my_argc; i++)
```